# How do I enforce a matcher from jest when using aws-sdk-client-mock-jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, aws-sdk

I have some unit tests where I am using `aws-sdk-client-mock-jest` to mock `DynamoDB` operations. I am importing the following packages like so:

```
import "aws-sdk-client-mock-jest";
const {DynamoDBClient} = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const {QueryCommand} = require("@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb");
const {mockClient} = require("aws-sdk-client-mock");
```

In my unit tests, I am using the mocks like this:

```
const ddbMock = mockClient(DynamoDBClient);

test("Received customer", async () => {
    ddbMock.on(QueryCommand).resolves({
        "name": "customer",
        "data": "some data"
    });
    const db = new DbRepository();

    const customer = await db.getCustomerAsync();
    // some assertions
    expect(customer).toHaveProperty("name", "customer");
});
```

However, when the toHaveProperty() is called an error is thrown which states: `TypeError: this.customTesters is not iterable`

What am I doing wrong here?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

I tried to use the expect library as mentioned [here](https://github.com/m-radzikowski/aws-sdk-client-mock#jest-matchers) but that does not work.

My unit tests are JS files.